# How to waive Xrays vision in latest Firefox WebExtension?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I am following the guide [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Xray_vision):

I want to waive Xrays vision of an iframe:

```
var foo = $(Components.utils.waiveXrays($("#foobar").get(0).contentWindow.document));
```

The above is running in a content script with manifest.json like the following:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": /* something */,
      "css": ["content.css"],
      "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.js","content.js"]
    }
  ]
```

But I will get an undefined object error:

```
[firefox/index.js][debug] Firefox stderr: JavaScript error: , line 0: Error: Components.utils is undefined
```

I think the guide on Mozilla website **is outdated**. It is not for pure WebExtension implementation.

What should be the correct latest method now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple of days of research (and asking in mozilla firefox mailing list). I already found out the solution. The correct guide is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Comparison_with_the_Add-on_SDK) (as of 2017 May 14):

> In the SDK, content scripts can share objects with page scripts, using
>   techniques like unsafeWindow and createObjectIn. In WebExtensions, the
>   unsafeWindow is available via wrappedJSObject instead. All the export
>   helper functions are available, too.

If I want to access the waived xrays version of window object, I should use:

```
window.wrappedJSObject
```

If there is an iframe within the page and I want to access the object inside it. Here is one of the way:

```
document.getElementById("the_iframe").contentWindow.wrappedJSObject
```

However, I found that if the iframe is in **cross-domain, the wrappedJSObject will be not accessible** (as of Firefox version 51.0.1). I need to seek another method as follow:

Provide a content script that inject all child iframe and then implement a background script that provide a [messaging bridge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_background_scripts) between the child iframe and the top page:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.something"],
      "css": ["content.css"],
      "all_frames": true, /* ADD THIS LINE */
      "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.js","content.js"]
    }
  ]
```

In content.js, do something like that:

```
if(window.top == window.self) { // main
  main();
}
else if(window.name == "frameA") { // match frameA
　　browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    /* Check the message msg and then access the waived X rays vision by window.wrappedJSObject */
     if(msg matches something) {
       var ret = window.wrappedJSObject.foobar(msg.data);
       /* Send back the return value to background.js by browser.runtime.sendMessage */
       browser.runtime.sendMessage({"returnVal": ret, "from": "frameA"}); 
     }
    }
  });
}
```

In background.js, do some message forwarding:

```
function forward_to_all(r)
{
  var forwardMessage = function(tabs) {
    for(let tab of tabs) {
      browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,r);
    }
  }
  browser.tabs.query({currentWindow:true, active:true}).then(forwardMessage);
}
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
  if(msg matches something) {
    forward_to_all(msg);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't meant to be able to waive xrays in firefox webextensions, if you are able to then it's a bug that would quickly be disabled.

> I think the guide on Mozilla website is outdated.

Indeed.

> What should be the correct latest method now?

what you want to do (ie waive xray wrappers) is not possible.  Probably best to think about a new way to achieve what you want, whatever that is (I can't tell by the description).